# JQM RC2 data-role="header" not styling with dynamic load

Tags: jquery-mobile

Neither my simple 'header' or 'footer' gets styled: all the other widgets (controlgroups, collapsible-sets, list etc) style as expected.

I'm  reloading everything in the data-role="page"
and then rebuilding the page like

```
$("#standings").load(url, function (content, status) {
        $("#standings").trigger("create");
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
```

Everything in the data-role='content' styles fine on load.  I have two 'controlgroups' outside of the content that style correctly but neither the header or footer pick up any styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `trigger("pagecreate")` instead of `trigger("create")`... even if this is usually not recommended... :S

So, you'll get something like this:

```
$("#standings").load(url, function (content, status) {
        $("#standings").trigger("pagecreate");
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});
```

I thougth you may wanna have a look at this link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2703

---

Otherwise, you can try to apply the classes directly to your header.

Check this link for more infomation: [JQuery Mobile trigger('create') command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088837/jquery-mobile-triggercreate-command-not-working)

---

Hope this helps.