# ajax replace data-theme but trigger('create') or listview('refresh') doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, data-theme

Greeting,

I am trying to replace data-theme but never apply change with `trigger.('create')` or `listview('refresh')`

Please test my code at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fanartie/Yz9mc/6/)

Thank you for your help

Here is my code ...

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
  <div data-role="content">
    <div>
      <ul id="uuu" data-role="listview">
        <li id="kkk" data-theme="e">fail change to theme A</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
$('#uuu').append('<li data-theme="a">success change to theme A</li>');

$('#kkk').attr('data-theme', 'a');  // I need do this through ajax

// ======

$('#home').trigger('create');
$("#uuu").listview("refresh");
$("#kkk").listview("refresh"); // this is not working ?
```

Comment: what does trigger('create') do? it looks like a custom event.

Comment: It's a jQuery mobile event that when triggered causes the page to get re-rendered.

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html - i don't see it.

Comment: *"it was a"* then. guess that has been removed.

Comment: in any case, i googled and see what you are saying. also i see a duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088837/jquery-mobile-triggercreate-command-not-working

Comment: Thanks apprentice, the URL you provided is not the same issue, but still thanks for your advice, actually I google a lots and problem not resolved yet. Hope you may help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh your ul:

```
$("#uuu").listview("refresh")
```

for more info: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-methods.html[1](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-methods.html)

Comment: I revised my code at http://jsfiddle.net/fanartie/Yz9mc/4/ but apply .listview("refresh") to "kkk" still not working, any idea ?