# jquery mobile trigger('create') method doesn't work with iframe

Tags: jquery-mobile, iframe

When I try to call .trigger('create') method to iframe contents, it does not work and css classes are not applied to input:text elements. but when I call .trigger('create') method for html content outside the iframe, it works

please go to this link ['here'](http://jsfiddle.net/m5maJ/1/) on jsfiddle and click on "load mobile view"

javascript code

```
$('#mobile_view').contents().find('body').append("<div id='fbm_mob_menu'></div>");

$("#load_mobileview").click(function(){
    var content = ' <form class="fbm_contactform">\
    <div>Contact Us</div>\
    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="name" >Name</label>\
    <input name="name" type="text" class="m-field" /></div>\
    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="email">Email</label>\
    <input name="email" type="text" class="m-field" /></div>\
    <div data-role="fieldcontain"><label >Message</label>\
    <input name="message" type="text" class="m-field" /></div>\
    <input name="submitButton" type="submit" class="m-field" value="Send Message"  /></div>\
    </form> ';
$("#mobile_view").contents().find("#fbm_mob_menu").before(content);
$("#mobile_view").contents().find(".fbm_contactform").trigger("create");      
});
```

html code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="load_mobileview" >load mobile view </a>
<iframe id="mobile_view"></iframe>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem by writing a javascript function inside iframe. and calling that function outside from the iframe.

in iFrame

```
<script>
window.trigerCreate =function(){$(".fbm_contactform").trigger("create");}
</script>
```

parent

```
window.frames[0].trigerCreate();
```

Answer (score 1):

iFrame contents should not be "easily" accessible, so to me this is correct behavior.

If you check the [jQuery Mobile API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/) examples, you can see that all pages are done using iFrames and every iFrame has it's own version of jQuery Mobile.

So if you have an `iframe`, include JQM inside the iFrame and everything should be allright.

Comment: I've already included JQM inside the iframe html. but I need to dynamically add contents to iframe and apply jquery mobile styles to that content. I'm working on a project which convert websites to mobile websites. so I have to find a way to do that.